# In Visual Studio 2017, how to use an existing Android SDK for Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2017, hybrid-mobile-app, android-sdk-manager

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for Creating Cordova projects, I have an Android SDK already installed on my machine, how to configure Visual Studio to use it, instead of downloading a new instance of Android SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get to know the answer, please follow the below steps:

1. Choose **Tools** menu >**Options**. 
   [image: 1]]
2. Choose **Tools for Apache Cordova** >**Environment Variable Overrides**.
   [image]
3. Check the checkbox against **ANDROID_HOME** and click on Browse(**...**) button.

[image]

4. Select your existing Android SDK folder, and click **OK**.

[image]

5. It is recommended to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Your response should be marked as answered. It works.

Comment: However, this does NOT allow deploying apps on the external Android emulators. VS2017 still requires the installation of its obsolete API23 to deploy to emulator, any workaround to fix this?

Comment: for xamarin it's almost the same - just go to "xamarin" after clicking on "options"

Comment: @andreszs Did you found an workaround? My Visual Studio always wants to install API23 (but I already installed it) and I am unable to deployd to a running emulator.

Comment: @Hamburml the only workaround with VS2017 is to launch the emulator from the CLI, as explained in [this article](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/). I'm still using VS2015 for this and other reasons mentioned there.

Comment: @andreszs Thanks! That's very frustrating... Have you tried Xamarin Tools and the Xamarin Android SDK Manager / Emulator Setup? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin If I find some free time I will try (and hope) that it's compatible. Would like to use VS 2017, new Android SDK and Android Emulator with VS 2017 debugging...